# Overflowing elements clipped

Tags: react-native

[image]I'm trying to create a FAB style button (iOS) that overlays the bottom of the container it's in by 50%.

However, all content overflowing the edge of the containing element is being clipped. I don't use overflow:'hidden'.

Any suggestions?

```
<View style={{
marginHorizontal:12,
borderRadius:2,
borderWidth:1,
}}>
  <View style={{
      flex:0,
      height:175
  }}>
    <View style={{
        position:'absolute',
        bottom:-24,
        right:16,
    }}>
        <FABButton icon="plus" size={24}/>
    </View>
  </View>

  <View style={{
    flex:0,

  }}>
    <View style={{
        marginTop:24,
        marginHorizontal:24,
        marginBottom:16
    }}>
      <Text style={[fontSize:24}>My Title</Text>
      <Text style={{fontSize:14}}>My subtitle</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the problem... or better yet set this up at https://rnplay.org and provide a link so we can see what's going on better

Comment: So, what's happening is not that the content is clipped. It's that the subsequent pane overlaps the content. Apparently, subsequent panes have a z-index on top of the previous one

Comment: Ah, okay... maybe this will help then. "zIndex can be controlled by re-arranging the components when you render. The later views will be drawn above the earlier ones." https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/698